# What will be the asymptotic time complexity of the following function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I came across this problem on asymptotic complexity of a function:

The complexities of 3 functions are as follows:

**f(n)** = **O(n)**

**g(n)** = Big-Omega(n)

**h(n)** = Theta(n)

So what will be the asymptotic complexity of the resultant function **[f(n).g(n)] + h(n)**

I can figure out the answer to this will be Big-Omega(n) by elementary hit and trial. For example if I say **f(n) = n** and **g(n) = n** and **h(n) = n**. So we can say **f(n) is O(n)** and **g(n) is Big-Omega(n)** and **h(n) is Theta(n)**. Now **f(n).g(n)** is **n<sup>2</sup>** and this will be **Big-Omega(n) but not O(n)**. Now adding this to h(n) is **n<sup>2</sup>+n**. Which also is **Big-Omega(n) but not Theta(n)**.

But I'm not able to figure out a proper logical or mathematical proof to this. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: really a thoughtful question

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at a logical explanation:

- `f(n) = O(n)` means that `f`'s running time **is at most** linear (may be constant time).
- `h(n) = Theta(n)` means that `h`'s running time running **is** linear.
- `g(n) = Big-Omega(n)` means that `g`'s running time is **atleast** linear (may be polynomial, exponential... we don't know).

Now let's analyse the best case: `f(n)` is constant time, `g(n)` is linear, `h(n)` is linear. what can we say about the function `f(n)*g(n)+h(n)`? that it's also linear.

What can we say about the worst case? **nothing**, as we have no clue about the behaviour of `g(n)` in the worst case.

So we can conclude that `f(n)*g(n)+h(n) = Big-Omega(n)` as this function is linear at the best case.

Comment: Hmm..well that does make some sense. But if it's linear in it's best case then isn't it possible that it might be O(n) at it's best case (say it's  best case is it's worst case as well since we can't definitely say what it's worst case will be)?

Comment: It is possible that `g` is linear, but not necessarily. you don't have any worst case information about `g`, thus you don't have information about the worst case of `f*g` (and therefor can't use any big-O annotation for this function).